# Error creating a React app with the command 'npx create-react-app ./client'

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, webrtc

I'm making a video chat. Every time I create a React app with the command `npx create-react-app ./client` I'm having this issue. How to fix it, please?

```
Creating a new React app in `D:\webrtc\client`.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.

Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

yarn add v1.22.10
[1/4] Resolving packages...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
error postcss@8.2.6: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "^10 || ^12 || >=14". Got "13.14.0"
error Found incompatible module.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.

Aborting installation.
  yarnpkg add --exact react react-dom react-scripts cra-template --cwd D:\webrtc\client has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting generated file... yarn.lock
Deleting client/ from D:\webrtc
Done.
```

Comment: As the error message says, the version of `postcss` used requires specific versions of node: 10.x, 12.x or 14.x (and above). Your version of node appears to be 13.14.0, which is not one of the above. Upgrading node to version 14 or downgrading to 12 would be a good start.

Comment: What @rmlockerd wrote looks like the key to me! 

After that, if you're looking for a tutorial on building a video chat app with React using a library that has already built on top of WebRTC, [this tutorial](https://dev.to/trydaily/build-a-video-chat-app-in-minutes-with-react-and-daily-js-481c) might be helpful. Good luck!